# Error with showing a new form in C#

Tags: c#

I need your help please
I have created a form and insert a timer & progress bar into it
when the value of progress bar reach to 100% I want to close this form and open the main form of my program
I write this code but when I Run the program it show this error  :
( Form that is already displayed modally cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Close the form before calling showDialog.)
How I can resolve this problem

```
    Form1 MainForm = new Form1();
    public Welcome_window()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Start();
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Increment(10);
        if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
        {
            this.Visible = false;
            MainForm.Visible = false;                                       
            MainForm.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();                          
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you set visibility to false and then call the showDialog method ?
Remove this line :
MainForm.Visible = false;                                       
         
and change this :
   MainForm.ShowDialog();

to this : 
MainForm.Show();

Comment: or close then show

Comment: It would be a much better OOP approach to subscribe to an event on your progress bar form and show the main form when that event fires.

Comment: when fire the close method, the application will exit I think ! So it's better to show then close

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a form open a modal form and then close itself. This is because a modal form is a child form and if you try to close the parent, then its not really a child anymore. So, as @kaj suggested, use Show instead of ShowDialog

Comment: As mentioned anove since your closing the current form maun form should not be set to invisible and you should not use ShowDialog since it wont be a dialog of the form your closing now.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad I choose the ShowDialog command because it make the main form display and I made the visibility of welcome window form is False to hide it first then close it after showing the second form which I called MainForm

Comment: I just remembered that ShowDialog will stop `this.Close()` from executing until the modal form is closed. So basically disregard everything I said =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you don't stop the timer, so the tick event will be fired even if the progress already reached 100%.

```
Form1 MainForm = new Form1();
public Welcome_window()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer1.Start();
}
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Increment(10);
    if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
    {
        timer1.Stop(); 

        this.Visible = false;                                      
        MainForm.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();                
    }
}
```

Comment: your are making the same mistake when using ShowDialog() since the first form will be hidden then closed !! It must be Show()

Comment: @kaj no, `form1` will be hidden when the `form2` is shown and `form1` will be closed when the user closes `form2`.

Comment: That's right, but I think he is trying to close the first form, On the other hand, it's aggressive since it's better to free up the resources instead of let them running meaningless

Comment: @kaj well you don't know what his full code in `form1` is, maybe there is a reason he needs to keep it open. But you are right, if there is no reason, he should close it right away.

Comment: @Pulle you are right , the problem caused because the timer wasn't stop , Thank you a lot

Comment: @Pulle this is the full code in form1 which I called it Welcome_window , my idea is to show this form for 10 seconds then close it and show the main form of my program like the interface of Photoshop for example

Comment: @SilverHawk ok, so as kaj mentioned, you should close `form1` right away, because your code will stop at `MainForm.ShowDialog();` until `MainForm` is closed.